# text rotation css in IE vs chrome and FF text is not visible

Tags: html, css

Hello all I am trying to setup a sidebar navigation with html CSS and jquery that allows the user to click on a button the buttons will disappear and the menu will slide out from the left side of the page.

You can view a working sample of this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rlcrews/r5H9Z/)

I'm trying to figure out why the text does not appear within the div element visully in Chrome but it appears in IE. The desired effect is to have the text rotated -90 deg within the div tag. It appears to be there just not visible?

I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set base placement of rotated elements using that code:

```
-ms-transform-origin:50% 50%;
-webkit-transform-origin:50% 50%;
-moz-transform-origin:50% 50%;
-o-transform-origin:50% 50%;
```

I suggest to you to write it in a new class to apply in every rotated divs.